# no suitable image found when installing Oracle on Mac OSX

Tags: oracle, mac-osx, mac, installation, oracle10g

I'm installing Oracle Database 10g Release 2 (10.2.0.4) for MAC OS X on Intel x86-64

I have Mac OS X 10.6.7, running at Intel Mac.

When I start installing, I am faced to the following error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/tmp/OraInstall2011-04-02_05-15-54PM/oui/lib/mac_osx/liboraInstaller.dylib:  no suitable image found.  Did find:  /private/tmp/OraInstall2011-04-02_05-15-54PM/oui/lib/mac_osx/liboraInstaller.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1823)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1699)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
>           at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1020)
>           at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.unix.OiipuUnixOps.loadNativeLib(OiipuUnixOps.java:404)
>           at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.unix.OiipuUnixOps.(OiipuUnixOps.java:127)
>           at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgEnvironment.getEnv(OiipgEnvironment.java:203)
>           at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixEnvironmentOps.getEnv(OiixEnvironmentOps.java:62)
>           at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickInstaller.getHomeLoc(OiocOneClickInstaller.java:774)
>           at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickDB.createSubCenterPanel(OiocOneClickDB.java:409)
>           at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickDB.createPanel1(OiocOneClickDB.java:301)
>           at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickDB.createCenterPanel(OiocOneClickDB.java:252)
>           at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickInstaller.init(OiocOneClickInstaller.java:365)
>           at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickInstaller.createFrameElements(OiocOneClickInstaller.java:326)
>           at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickInstaller.main(OiocOneClickInstaller.java:1333)
>       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no oraInstaller in java.library.path
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1754)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
>           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
>           at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.unix.OiipuUnixOps.loadNativeLib(OiipuUnixOps.java:422)
>           at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.unix.OiipuUnixOps.(OiipuUnixOps.java:127)
>           at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgEnvironment.getEnv(OiipgEnvironment.java:203)
>           at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixEnvironmentOps.getEnv(OiixEnvironmentOps.java:62)
>           at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickInstaller.getHomeLoc(OiocOneClickInstaller.java:774)
>           at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickDB.createSubCenterPanel(OiocOneClickDB.java:409)
>           at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickDB.createPanel1(OiocOneClickDB.java:301)
>           at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickDB.createCenterPanel(OiocOneClickDB.java:252)
>           at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickInstaller.init(OiocOneClickInstaller.java:365)
>           at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickInstaller.createFrameElements(OiocOneClickInstaller.java:326)
>           at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickInstaller.main(OiocOneClickInstaller.java:1333)

Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: Welcome to the oracle world...

Comment: ...or Mac OS X for that matter

Answer (score 2):

You need to force 32 bit (`-J-d32`) when you `./runInstaller`
e.g.:

```
/db/Disk1/runInstaller -J-d32
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure you met the [software prerequisites](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b25286/pre_install.htm#CIHFICFD)? In particular, you must have JDK 1.4.2_05 already installed.

Comment: Actually there is only build-in JDK in Mac OS X

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with Lion JDK 1.4.2.

- Edit Oracle's `db/Disk1/install/oraparam.ini`
- Change the line `JRE_MEMORY_OPTIONS="-mx150m"` to `JRE_MEMORY_OPTIONS="-d32 -mx150m"`
- Run `db/Disk1/runInstaller`

Similar with other Oracle installs.